# Find a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, expected-value

I have a problem with finding an example of a sequence of nonnegative random variables $X_1, \ldots$ with values in integers s.t. $\mathbb{E}X_n \rightarrow \infty$ and

- $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n>0)<1$ (first case),
- $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n>0)=1$ (second case).

I think in the second case it can be a sequence $X_n=n$. Is it good reasoning? What with the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: your answer for the second case is good. Can you modify it to obtain an example such that $P(X_n = 0) = P(X_n > 0) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$ and $\Bbb{E}(X_n) = \frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: $X_n=0$  when $n$ is odd and $X_n=\frac{n}{2}$ in the contrary case? I don't have better idea. It seems that the condition with the expected value will be not fulfilled... Namely its limit won't be infinity.

Comment: How about tossing a fair coin to decide whether $X_n = 0$ or $X_n = n$?

Comment: I don't see here that $\mathbb{E}X_n$ is approaching infinity. Maybe it's trivial because of the fact that $\mathbb{E}X_n$ diverges. Am I right?

Comment: $\Bbb{E}(X_n) = \frac{n}{2}$ is a sequence of numbers than tends to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. That's what the question is asking you for.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It occured to be easy.